# Function to replace list with numbers and signs in python

Tags: python, regex, function, replace

I have an array:

```
array(['Amazon', 'Amazon mix', 'Amazon, ICS', 'Beniano', 'Blend',
   'Blend-Forastero,Criollo', 'CCN51', 'Criollo', 'Criollo (Amarru)',
   'Criollo (Ocumare 61)', 'Criollo (Ocumare 67)',
   'Criollo (Ocumare 77)', 'Criollo (Ocumare)', 'Criollo (Porcelana)',
   'Criollo (Wild)', 'Criollo, +', 'Criollo, Forastero',
   'Criollo, Trinitario', 'EET', 'Forastero', 'Forastero (Amelonado)',
   'Forastero (Arriba)', 'Forastero (Arriba) ASS',
   'Forastero (Arriba) ASSS', 'Forastero (Catongo)',
   'Forastero (Nacional)', 'Forastero (Parazinho)',
   'Forastero(Arriba, CCN)', 'Forastero, Trinitario', 'Matina',
   'NA_bean', 'Nacional', 'Nacional (Arriba)', 'Other', 'Trinitario',
   'Trinitario (85% Criollo)', 'Trinitario (Amelonado)',
   'Trinitario (Scavina)', 'Trinitario, Criollo',
   'Trinitario, Forastero', 'Trinitario, Nacional',
   'Trinitario, TCGA'], dtype=object)
```

And I want to standardize them to remove the amount of unique values. So I created a function:

```
def std_bean(text):
    replace = [
        ['\(',''],['\)',''],
        ['Amazon mix|Amazon, ICS|Blend-Forastero,Criollo|Criollo, Trinitario|Forastero, Trinitario|Trinitario 85% Criollo|Trinitario, Criollo|Trinitario, Forastero|Trinitario, Nacional','Blend'],
        ['Forastero Arriba|Forestero ASS|Forestero ASSS|Forastero Nacional|Forastero Catongo|Forastero Parazinho|Forastero Arriba ASS|ForasteroArriba, CCN|Forastero Arriba ASSS|Forastero Amelonado','Forastero'],
        ['Criollo Ocumare 77', 'Criollo'],
        ['Criollo Ocumare 61', 'Criollo'],
        ['Criollo Ocumare', 'Criollo'],
        ['Criollo Wild', 'Criollo'],
        ['Criollo, +', 'Criollo'],
        ['Criollo+', 'Criollo'],
        ['Criollo 67', 'Criollo'],
        ['Criollo, Forastero', 'Criollo'],
        ['Criollo Amarru', 'Criollo'],
        ['Forestero ASSS', 'Forastero'],
        ['Forastero ASS', 'Forastero'],
        ['Forestero', 'Forastero'],
        ['Trinitario Amelonado', 'Trinitario'],
        ['Forestero ASSS', 'Forastero'],
        ['Nacional Arriba', 'Nacional'],
        ['Trinitario, TCGA', 'Trinitario'],
        ['Criollo Porcelana','Criollo'],
        ['ForasteroS', 'Forastero']
    ]
    for i, j in replace:
        text = re.sub(i, j, text)
    return(text)
df['bean_type'].str.replace('.','').apply(std_bean).unique()
```

After applying it I still have a values such as 'Criollo+', 'CriolloForastero' and other that I just can't replace I don't know how to fix it...

```
array(['NA_bean', 'Criollo', 'Trinitario', 'Forastero', 'Blend', 'CCN51',
   'Nacional', 'Beniano', 'Criollo+', 'Amazon', 'EET',
   'Trinitario Scavina', 'CriolloForastero', 'Matina', 'Other'],
  dtype=object)
```

Could someone help me improve the function? I just want to merge the ones that are alike. Tag as Blend those who have more than 1 type of bean (either with a comma or that says mix or has a name of another type of bean inside the parenthesis) and leave the name that isn't in parenthesis for those who aren't blends.

The final output I want is to have only 'Blend, Criollo, Forastero, NA_bean, Matina, Nacional, among others'

I want to group these as Blend:
'Amazon mix|Amazon, ICS|Blend-Forastero,Criollo|Criollo, Trinitario|Forastero, Trinitario|Trinitario 85% Criollo|Trinitario, Criollo|Trinitario, Forastero|Trinitario, Nacional'

I want these as Forastero:
['Forastero Arriba|Forestero ASS|Forestero ASSS|Forastero Nacional|Forastero Catongo|Forastero Parazinho|Forastero Arriba ASS|ForasteroArriba, CCN|Forastero Arriba ASSS|Forastero Amelonado','Forastero']

And so on.

Comment: When using regular expressions you must know which characters are special and must escape them if they should be taken as is (`+` is such a character)

Comment: Can you explain better what do you need? Some examples and expected output for input would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow, It seems like we have to build a custom rule rather than find & replace.

Please find the below code & check if that works for you,

```
import pandas as pd

bean_type = {'bean_type': ['Amazon', 'Amazon mix', 'Amazon, ICS', 'Beniano', 'Blend',
                           'Blend-Forastero,Criollo', 'CCN51', 'Criollo', 'Criollo (Amarru)',
                           'Criollo (Ocumare 61)', 'Criollo (Ocumare 67)',
                           'Criollo (Ocumare 77)', 'Criollo (Ocumare)', 'Criollo (Porcelana)',
                           'Criollo (Wild)', 'Criollo, +', 'Criollo, Forastero',
                           'Criollo, Trinitario', 'EET', 'Forastero', 'Forastero (Amelonado)',
                           'Forastero (Arriba)', 'Forastero (Arriba) ASS',
                           'Forastero (Arriba) ASSS', 'Forastero (Catongo)',
                           'Forastero (Nacional)', 'Forastero (Parazinho)',
                           'Forastero(Arriba, CCN)', 'Forastero, Trinitario', 'Matina',
                           'NA_bean', 'Nacional', 'Nacional (Arriba)', 'Other', 'Trinitario',
                           'Trinitario (85% Criollo)', 'Trinitario (Amelonado)',
                           'Trinitario (Scavina)', 'Trinitario, Criollo',
                           'Trinitario, Forastero', 'Trinitario, Nacional',
                           'Trinitario, TCGA']}

df = pd.DataFrame(bean_type)


def blend_count(text):
    bean_types = ['criollo', 'trinitario', 'nacional', 'forastero']
    _blend_count = 0
    if 'blend' in text.lower():
        return 0
    for _bean_type in bean_types:
        if _bean_type in text.lower():
            _blend_count += 1
    return _blend_count


def blend_category(text):
    _blend_count = blend_count(text)
    _text = text.lower()
    if any(x in _text for x in ['blend', 'amazon']):
        return 'Blend'
    elif 'trinitario' in _text:
        if _blend_count == 1:
            return 'Trinitario'
        elif _blend_count > 1:
            return 'Blend'
    elif _text.startswith('forastero'):
        return 'Forastero'
    elif _text.startswith('nacional'):
        return 'Nacional'
    elif _text.startswith('criollo'):
        return 'Criollo'
    else:
        return text


df['blend_category'] = df['bean_type'].apply(blend_category)
# df['blend_count'] = df['bean_type'].apply(blend_count)

print(df)
```

Below is my output

```
                   bean_type blend_category
0                     Amazon          Blend
1                 Amazon mix          Blend
2                Amazon, ICS          Blend
3                    Beniano        Beniano
4                      Blend          Blend
5    Blend-Forastero,Criollo          Blend
6                      CCN51          CCN51
7                    Criollo        Criollo
8           Criollo (Amarru)        Criollo
9       Criollo (Ocumare 61)        Criollo
10      Criollo (Ocumare 67)        Criollo
11      Criollo (Ocumare 77)        Criollo
12         Criollo (Ocumare)        Criollo
13       Criollo (Porcelana)        Criollo
14            Criollo (Wild)        Criollo
15                Criollo, +        Criollo
16        Criollo, Forastero        Criollo
17       Criollo, Trinitario          Blend
18                       EET            EET
19                 Forastero      Forastero
20     Forastero (Amelonado)      Forastero
21        Forastero (Arriba)      Forastero
22    Forastero (Arriba) ASS      Forastero
23   Forastero (Arriba) ASSS      Forastero
24       Forastero (Catongo)      Forastero
25      Forastero (Nacional)      Forastero
26     Forastero (Parazinho)      Forastero
27    Forastero(Arriba, CCN)      Forastero
28     Forastero, Trinitario          Blend
29                    Matina         Matina
30                   NA_bean        NA_bean
31                  Nacional       Nacional
32         Nacional (Arriba)       Nacional
33                     Other          Other
34                Trinitario     Trinitario
35  Trinitario (85% Criollo)          Blend
36    Trinitario (Amelonado)     Trinitario
37      Trinitario (Scavina)     Trinitario
38       Trinitario, Criollo          Blend
39     Trinitario, Forastero          Blend
40      Trinitario, Nacional          Blend
41          Trinitario, TCGA     Trinitario
```

Answer (score 0):

The source of your problem is `Criollo, +` used as a regex pattern.

Note that this pattern actually means:

- find `Criollo` and a comma,
- then find a space, **occurring 1 or more times** (`+` in regex is a repetition
  count for the preceding expression, in this case a space).

This pattern matches also `Criollo,` in `Criollo, Forastero`.
Since this replacement actually deletes `,` (a comma and a space), you get
`CriolloForastero`.

To fix the problem, change this pattern to `Criollo, \+` (quote the `+` with
a backslash, to match them literally).

`['Criollo\+', 'Criollo']` in your replacement list is probably not needed.

### Edit

You may also try another approach:

The function to apply to each `bean_type` field should:

1. Check whether the text contains `Blend` (anywhere). If it does, return `Blend`.
2. Find all words (sequences of letters) - bean names. When the pattern contains
   a single capturing group, the result of `findall` is a list of all "findings".
3. If only a **single word** has been found (the result list contains only
   1 item), return just this item.
4. Otherwise (**multiple** bean names found) return `Blend`.

Below you have an example program:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
def std_bean_name(text):
    """Generate standard bean name"""
    if re.search('Blend', text, re.IGNORECASE):
        return 'Blend'
    res = re.findall(r"([a-z]+)", text, re.IGNORECASE)
    if len(res) == 1:
        return res[0]
    else:
        return 'Blend'
# Source data
lst = ['Amazon', 'Amazon mix', 'Amazon, ICS', 'Beniano', 'Blend',
    'Blend-Forastero,Criollo', 'CCN51', 'Criollo', 'Criollo (Amarru)',
    'Criollo (Ocumare 61)', 'Criollo (Ocumare 67)',
    'Criollo (Ocumare 77)', 'Criollo (Ocumare)', 'Criollo (Porcelana)',
    'Criollo (Wild)', 'Criollo, +', 'Criollo, Forastero',
    'Criollo, Trinitario', 'EET', 'Forastero', 'Forastero (Amelonado)',
    'Forastero (Arriba)', 'Forastero (Arriba) ASS',
    'Forastero (Arriba) ASSS', 'Forastero (Catongo)',
    'Forastero (Nacional)', 'Forastero (Parazinho)',
    'Forastero(Arriba, CCN)', 'Forastero, Trinitario', 'Matina',
    'NA_bean', 'Nacional', 'Nacional (Arriba)', 'Other', 'Trinitario',
    'Trinitario (85% Criollo)', 'Trinitario (Amelonado)',
    'Trinitario (Scavina)', 'Trinitario, Criollo',
    'Trinitario, Forastero', 'Trinitario, Nacional', 'Trinitario, TCGA']
# Create a DataFrame
beans = pd.DataFrame(data=lst, columns=['bean_type'])
# Generate standard bean names
beans['type2'] = beans['bean_type'].apply(std_bean_name)
# Show the detailed result (source / standard type)
print(beans)
# List unique bean names
print(beans['type2'].unique())
```

The last line prints:

```
['Amazon' 'Blend' 'Beniano' 'CCN' 'Criollo' 'EET' 'Forastero' 'Matina'
 'Nacional' 'Other' 'Trinitario']
```

I tested the above program under *Python 3.6* and *Jupyter Notebook*.